# Importing Mobile Ads Unity plugin results in standard input InvalidOperationException

Tags: unity, google-play-services, admob

When I import Mobile Ads Unity plugin this error shows up. How can I fix it, and why am I getting this error?

[image]

While the “Resolving Android Dependencies” dialog and loading bar is open,  the following appears in the console:

```
InvalidOperationException: Standard input has not been redirected.
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_StandardInput ()
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 envVars, GooglePlayServices.IOHandler ioHandler, Boolean useShellExecution, Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.Run(System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 envVars, GooglePlayServices.IOHandler ioHandler)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 ()
UnityEngine.UnhandledExceptionHandler:<RegisterUECatcher>m__0(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
```